# Apple keeps rejecting app with AdMob because of bluetooth notification string not correct

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

Since IOS 13 came to live old 3 party APIs stopped working, In my app i needed to fix few because of that so i needed to fit it to IOS 13.
Since then Apple keeps rejecting my app because of Bluetooth user notification is not correct.

I just don't know what to write there, It is so annoying. I have to add it because of AdMobs and there is nowhere to say what to write over there.

I don't user BT in my app, it is just the AdMobs beacons that needs it probably.

I've tried:

[image]

and

[image]

And i will probably will have the same issue with the calendar message also.

When i try to remove it they demand it and then not approving it.... I understand maybe the first one but what wrong with the the second one? why is that no clear enough for them?

10x

Comment: mmm weird.. I'm using AdMob and did not get a request for bluetooth nor an authorization request (app got approved today)

Comment: really weird...

Comment: Hi @Erez, my app also rejected due to bluetooth notification. Can you suggest me how can i get it approved

Comment: @SureshVutukuru, I'm actually stuck on this... Apple refuses to help me at all. They ignore the screen shots i am sending them and don't try to understand that the their build process is telling me that i have to add the BT notification and then the person that is checking the app tells me that i cant add it because i don't have BT in my app. They are really annoying and for now there is nothing i can do about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see apple docs below: https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/app-architecture/requesting-permission/

> Explain why your app needs the information. Provide custom text (known
>   as a purpose string or usage description string) for display in the
>   system's permission request alert, and include an example. Keep the
>   text short and specific, use sentence case, and be polite so people
>   don't feel pressured. There’s no need to include your app name—the
>   system already identifies your app. For developer guidance, see
>   Protecting the User's Privacy.

you're not explaining exactly why you need access to bluetooth. you must be specific. saying, "XYZ app needs access to bluetooth to interact with beacons to serve you location based advertisements"

something like that should do. no cutting corners, no trying to put it off on Google, just say it like it is and you'll likely pass through app approval without a problem.

Comment: I wonder why do i need to allow BT and @vale does not, that is weird, we both are using AdMob. This is weird. I tried to contact both Apple and Google and didnt get and response...

Comment: If you have any knowledge in regarding to why do adMobs needs Calendar permissions also and how to write the statement for that i would appreciate it very much also. Cant figure out why do they need permissions